# Remove non alphabetic characters from a list of sentences in Python

Tags: python, string, list, text

starting from a list like this:

```
sentences = ["da quando è esplosa l'epidemia, ci sono stati -- i dati ufficiali sottostimano il fenomeno -- 92.522 morti, 2.725.106 cittadini colpiti dal virus, in questo momento 2.074 sono i ricoverati in terapia intensiva", 'ci sono 259 morti tra gli operatori sanitari e 118.856 sono quelli contagiati, a dimostrazione di un enorme sacrificio sostenuto con generosità e impegno', 'cifre che hanno messo a dura prova il sistema sanitario nazionale, sottraendo personale e risorse alla prevenzione e alla cura di altre patologie, con conseguenze pesanti sulla salute di tanti italiani', "l'aspettativa di vita, a causa della pandemia, è diminuita: fino a 4 - 5 anni nelle zone di maggior contagio; un anno e mezzo - due in meno per tutta la popolazione italiana"]
```

I want to obtain a list without numbers and symbols in each element, for eg.:

```
["da quando è esplosa l'epidemia ci sono stati i dati ufficiali sottostimano il fenomeno morti cittadini colpiti dal virus in questo momento sono i ricoverati in terapia intensiva", ...]
```

Comment: will edit my answer without numbers

Comment: Try using regular expressions https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_letters(x):
    n_s=[]
    for i in x:
        elem=" ".join([c for c in i.split(' ') if c.isalpha()])
        n_s.append(elem)
    return n_s
get_letters(sentences)
```

Output:

```
['da quando è esplosa ci sono stati i dati ufficiali sottostimano il fenomeno cittadini colpiti dal in questo momento sono i ricoverati in terapia intensiva',
 'ci sono morti tra gli operatori sanitari e sono quelli a dimostrazione di un enorme sacrificio sostenuto con generosità e impegno',
 'cifre che hanno messo a dura prova il sistema sanitario sottraendo personale e risorse alla prevenzione e alla cura di altre con conseguenze pesanti sulla salute di tanti italiani',
 'di a causa della è fino a anni nelle zone di maggior un anno e mezzo due in meno per tutta la popolazione italiana']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what you are filtering. Here is code for your data:

```
def filter(text):
    skip_space = True
    for ch in text:
        if skip_space and ch == ' ':
            continue
        skip_space = ch in '0123456789.-'
        if skip_space:
            continue
        yield ch

for sentence in sentences:
    result = ''.join(filter(sentence))
    print(result)
    print('=====')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentences = ["da quando è esplosa l'epidemia, ci sono stati -- i ..."]
answer = []                   # empty list
for i in sentences:
    sentence = i.split(" ")
    words = []
    for z in sentence:
        if z[0].isalpha():    # used z[0] because "l'epidemia".isalpha() == False
            words.append(z)
    answer.append(" ".join(words))
print(answer)
```